# a single line python code for getting the second list of file name if any of first list string match

Tags: python

I have two lists, I want to get the file name in the second list if any of the first list strings match in the second list. I want to get a file name with the single-line code if the string matches.

```py
list_1 = ['KNeighborsClassifier',
                     'ExtraTreesClassifier',
                     'LGBMClassifier',
                     'RandomForestClassifier',
                     'GradientBoostingClassifier',
                     'XGBClassifier',
                     'DecisionTreeClassifier']

list_2 = ['KNeighborsClassifier.pkl',
 'ExtraTreesClassifier.pkl',
 '.ipynb_checkpoints',
 'LGBMClassifier.pkl',
 'RandomForestClassifier.pkl',
 'mutual_info_parameter_tuning.txt',
 'GradientBoostingClassifier.pkl',
 'XGBClassifier.pkl',
 'DecisionTreeClassifier.pkl',
 'all_models_cv_results.pkl']

for string_name in list_1:
    file_name = [s for s in list_2 if string_name in s]
    print(file_name[0])
```

What is the single line of python code to get the file name from the second list if any of the first list  string match in second list ?

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question into something intelligible

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @arifaChan I want to get the file name of second list, I already got the filename, But I want to write this code in a single line.

Comment: Suggest considering [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for the purpose.

Comment: @alphamu ~ I just deleted my entire answer about `set` because I overlooked the `.pkl` part. You'd have to filter out the filename extensions and then make a `set`. By that point it's more work than the version the OP currently has. Also a `set` will reorder the data ... which I guess matters, due to the OP using an index to retrieve the name.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Oh, I see now. Yes, in that case file extensions and file names order are indeed valuable piece of input data, making thus ```set``` not the best option.

Comment: What exactly are the parameters of your problem? Are you trying to get a list of all matches? The first file name? Will the names in the first list always have a matching file name in the second list...?

Answer (score 0):

One liner to print matched elements:

```
print(*[s for string_name in list_1 for s in list_2 if string_name in s], sep='\n')
```

Or store to a list:

```
file_name = [s for string_name in list_1 for s in list_2 if string_name in s]
print(file_name)

# ['KNeighborsClassifier.pkl', 'ExtraTreesClassifier.pkl', 'LGBMClassifier.pkl', 'RandomForestClassifier.pkl', 'GradientBoostingClassifier.pkl', 'XGBClassifier.pkl', 'DecisionTreeClassifier.pkl']
```